# Three.js specify a shader in JSON file and load a texture

Tags: javascript, json, 3d, three.js

So I'm supposed to define a custom shader within JSON 3d model.
This works, however in uniforms, I am unable to load a texture - if I assign it in JavaScript, everything is fine, so I know shader is loaded correctly.(other values in uniforms works)

```
"name": "mat_lacquer",

"metadata": {
    "version": 4.4,
    "type": "Material",
    "generator": "Material.toJSON"
},


"uuid": "87AACFC7-902F-4664-A3E7-CBF12B270FD1",
"type": "ShaderMaterial", "side": 2, "depthFunc": 3, "depthTest": true,
"depthWrite": true, "skinning": false, "morphTargets": false,

"uniforms": {
    "textureMap": {
        "type": "t",
        "value": " THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'matcaps/matcap.png' )"
    },
    "normalScale": {
        "type": "f",
        "value": 0
    },
    "texScale": {
        "type": "f",
        "value": 10
    },
    "useSSS": {
        "type": "f",
        "value": 0
    },
    "useScreen": {
        "type": "f",
        "value": 0
    }
},


"vertexShader": "\n\tvarying vec3 v..."
"fragmentShader": "\n\tvarying vec3 vRef..."
```

Now if I pass a texture value like this, it's black with  no error. If I pass it as `value: textureName` with textureName defined elsewhere in JSON, result is the same, although the texture is correctly loaded in other material. Any ideas?